# AVFoundation capture UIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, avfoundation

I'm trying to capture one or more UIImages programmatically using AVFoundation.
I set up the sessions and input devices and everything, but when I try to find explanations on how to actually take the photos, all I get is buffeled information about connections and what not.
I couldn't find a single example of actually taking photos and saving it to UIImage for further processing. All the example use a constant `kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary` Which doesn't seems to exist in iOS 5 SDK..

Can someone please provide me with a code or an explanation from top to bottom on how to take and save an image from the front facing camera to a UIImage using AVFoundation?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To use `kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary`, you should `#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>`.

All of the other information you seek is inside the AVFoundation Programming guide - particularly the [Media Capture](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2) section.

Comment: #import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>

Comment: Good point, I updated the answer to use the top-level header. Thanks Cameron.